# How to solve for $x$ if $xy+ab=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I solve for $x$ if $x\cdot y+a\cdot b=0$.

I was working through it and this doesn't line up:

$$xy+ab = 0$$

$$(ab+x)\cdot(ab+y) = 0$$

*divide both sides by $(ab+y)$*
$$(ab+x) = 0/(ab+y)$$

*$0/x = 0$ so:*
$$(ab+x) = 0$$

But that can't be true?!  If $a,x = 1$; $b,y = 0$: $1\cdot 0+1 \ne 0$

Where's my fault?

Comment: Why not just substract $ab$ and divide by $y$

Comment: How did you get $(ab+x)(ab+y)=0$?  It doesn't follow.

Comment: @michael-burr Um I forget what it's called?  It's the rule that goes thus: x*(a+b)=xa+xb.  Does it not also work for x+(a*b)?

Comment: You're describing the distributive law, but it is not applied correctly.  $(ab+x)(ab+y)=a^2b^2+aby+abx+xy$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How exactly did you infer that

$$
(ab+x)\cdot (ab+y) = 0
$$
from $xy+ab = 0$?

The "correct" way to do this is to consider $y$, $a$ and $b$ as constants, and simply shuffle the equation around till you put all terms other than $x$ on the other side.

Working through this,

$$xy + ab = 0$$
$$xy = -ab$$

Now, assuming $y \neq 0$,
$$x = -ab / y$$

Otherwise, if $y = 0$, no solution exists

Comment: yes, I had. Thanks for the correction

Comment: If $y=0$ no solution exists unless $a=0$ or $b=0$, as in this case every value for $x$ would be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

To solve for x :
$$xy+ab =0 \\ xy=-ab \\ x=\frac{-ab}{y}$$

Comment: How do you know that $y\neq 0$ ?